# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip: is it possible to avoid writing javascript?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've noticed that when using Bootstrap's [Tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), I still have to manually include this line in a javascript file to get it to work:

```js
$('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();​
```

However, quoting the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html):

> You can use all Bootstrap plugins purely through the markup API
>   without writing a single line of JavaScript. This is Bootstrap's first
>   class API and should be your first consideration when using a plugin.

But that's not what I see: http://jsfiddle.net/ccmyx/1/ (try to remove the Javascript part).

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have any element with a title attribute in your fiddle, plus, you're using Mootools instead of jQuery and don't have the JavaScript of the Bootstrap in.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste mistake. I updated the link!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, contrary to all other JavaScript components, both Tooltip and Popover do not support the data-api. This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips):

> **For performance reasons**, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt in. If you would like to use them just specify a selector option.

Comment: Missed that line in the doc. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Benjamin: You're welcome, I've actually ran into the same problem a couple of months ago, so that narrowed down the search a bit :)